# Building an $http request from form field in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, http

I am trying to build a basic AngularJS weather app that takes a users zip code from a form and makes an API call to get the current forecast. The app has 2 views/routes. The first view has an input field and a submit button to collect the user's zip. The second view will display the forecast.

What I want to have happen is have the user put a zip code into the form and upon submitting it, build a url to make an Http request call with. So my final url would look like:

baseURL + UserZipFromForm + .json

I tried using Angular's $http, but it won't let me pass in a variable for the url as its expecting a string.  I don't think what I am trying to do would qualify as a query parameter and I've read some things about creating a factory but I am a little turned around at the moment.

If I am using ng-Submit to trigger building the url, how do I make the $http request and put the response into the right scope for use in my forecast view?

html:

```
<div class="text-center">
  <h2>Enter Your Zip</h2>

  <form name="myForm" ng-submit="submitMyForm()">
    <input type="text" ng-model="zipCode" />
    <button type="submit" value="Submit">Submit!</button>
  </form>

  <pre>zip = <span ng-bind="zipCode"></span></pre>

</div>
```

JS:

```
    var  myWeather = angular.module('myWeather', ['ngRoute']);

    myWeather.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider

            // route for the home page
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl : 'views/home.html',
                controller  : 'mainController'
            })

            // route for the forecast page
            .when('/forecast', {
                templateUrl : 'views/forecast.html',
                controller  : 'mainController'
            });

            $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    });

    myWeather.controller('mainController', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', function($scope, $http, $location) {

      // create a message to display in our view
      $scope.greeting = 'Here is the weather for:';

      $scope.submitMyForm=function(){
        var data= $scope.zipCode;

        var url = "https://api.wunderground.com//" + data + ".json"

        console.log(url);

        $http({
          method: 'GET',
          url: url
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            $scope.weather = response.data.current_observation;


            return $scope.weather;
          }, function errorCallback(response) {

        });

      };
    }]);
```

Comment: Please post your existing code.

Comment: `baseURL + UserZipFromForm + .'json'` should work as url.

Comment: Code posted above